# A common word that describes the first level relation

Tags: nouns, kinship-terms

A common word that describes the first level relation.
First level relation:
Parent for an unmarried.
Spouse for a married

Answer (score 3):

*First-degree (blood) relatives* are parents, children, and siblings.  They each share on average one half of your genes.  These are also called your ***immediate family***, a term which includes your spouse despite that person (normally) not sharing genes with you.

I presume this is the term you are looking for.  In many cultures and legal systems, members of the immediate family have special rights in certain matters.

For the record:

- *Second-degree relatives* are aunts, uncles, grandparents, grandchildren, and half-siblings. They each share on average one quarter of your genes.
- *Third-degree relatives* are first cousins, great- or half-aunts/uncles, and great-grandparents/children.  They each share on average one eighth of your genes.

It keeps going from there in the obvious way.

Comment: Thank you for reoly. Let me use next-of-kin or immediate family. Thanks for all three responses.

Comment: The problem with *next of kin* is that it can be used for whoever is the current surviving closest relative, even if they are your second cousin, twice removed.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly used is *immediate family*. The one person (or in some cases, people) with the closest familial relationship (spouse, parents if no spouse, siblings if no parents) are also called *next-of-kin*.